# Pandas remove row if all values in that row are false

Tags: python, pandas, boolean

I am looking to tidy up some rows in my dataset

```
output = {
         'id1': ['False', 'False', 'False', 'False'],
         'id2': ['True', 'False', 'False', 'False'],
         'id3': ['True', 'False', 'True', 'False'],
         'id4': ['True', 'False', 'True', 'True'],
    }
```

So using the above row 2 contains all false
[image]

Due to this i wont need to use it so I would just like to remove it

```
newoutput = {
         'id1': ['False',  'False', 'False'],
         'id2': ['True',  'False', 'False'],
         'id3': ['True',  'True', 'False'],
         'id4': ['True',  'True', 'True'],
    }
```

I got as far as checking for rows with false in it

```
output.drop(output[output != False].index, inplace=True)
```

But that just looks at ANY value in row being False and not All

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I constructed `df` via `df = pd.DataFrame(output)`.

You can use

```
>>> df[df.replace({'False': False, 'True': True}).any(1)]
     id1    id2    id3   id4
0  False   True   True  True
2  False  False   True  True
3  False  False  False  True
```

I strongly suggest using booleans instead of strings to indicate `True` and `False`. In that case the solution is a simple reassignment to `df[df.any(1)]`.

Answer (score 9):

- This assumes a dataframe of `Boolean` values, not `string` type.
- As noted in the other answer, use [`.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html) to replace `string` with `Boolean` type.

### Given

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'id1': [True, False, False, False], 'id2': [True, False, False, False], 'id3': [True, False, True, False], 'id4': [True, False, True, True]})

     id1    id2    id3    id4
0   True   True   True   True
1  False  False  False  False
2  False  False   True   True
3  False  False  False   True
```

Use [`DataFrame.any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.any.html) to match at least one `True` with [boolean indexing](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing), which will remove rows that are all `False`.

```
df = df[df.any(axis=1)]

     id1    id2    id3   id4
0   True   True   True  True
2  False  False   True  True
3  False  False  False  True
```

Alternatively, to delete rows that are all `True`, use [`.all()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.all.html) and negate with [`~`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-operators).

```
df[~df.all(axis=1)]

     id1    id2    id3    id4
1  False  False  False  False
2  False  False   True   True
3  False  False  False   True
```