# Pandas drop rows when all columns in a subset of columns meet a condition

Tags: python, pandas

Have a list of columns and if all are zero for a row I want to delete.  Generating the list dynamically as number of plans will change. dmt_clean is the dataframe.

```
dmt_clean.head()

OptionNumber    TradeCategory   4015-7  4017-7  4019-7  4025-7  4030-6
0   1   Doors - Exterior    280.226822  280.226822  280.226822  280.226822  280.226822
1   1   Hardware    175.99  175.54  184.25  226.49  267.82
2   1   Trim - Interior 1818.783178 1904.233178 2252.523178 2589.283178 3323.953178
3   70000   Trim - Interior 0   0   0   0   0
4   70002   Trim - Interior 0   0   0   0   0

# get list of only plan number columns
l_plan_cols = []
for c in dmt_clean.columns:
    if re.search('\d{4}-\d{1}', c):
        l_plan_cols.append(c)

dmt_clean[l_plan_cols] == 0

    4015-7  4017-7  4019-7  4025-7  4030-6
0   False   False   False   False   False
1   False   False   False   False   False
2   False   False   False   False   False
3   True    True    True    True    True
4   True    True    True    True    True
5   True    True    False   True    True
6   False   False   False   True    False
```

Comment: `df[~df.all(axis=1)]`

Comment: This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62512594/7758804) from the duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

```
df = df.dropna(axis=0, how='all')
```